# How can I tell which thread a COM object is associated with? (STA)

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I have COM interop issues between managed and unmanaged STA code which I believe are due to trying to call into COM objects from the wrong thread.

Is there a way to actually *tell* which thread/apartment a COM object 'belongs' to in an STA setup? I cannot find a way in either C++ or C# and both would be useful!

Are there APIs to do this?

Comment: Apartment type (basically STA vs MTA) is defined by calling CoInitialize(Ex). It's usually the thread creator that calls this API which is often implicit (or attribute based like STAThreadAttribute) in .NET. There is only one MTA. You can determine what *type* of apartment the thread is in (GetApartmentState). Now, each object created during this thread execution will live in that apartment (the MTA or an STA if the thread is STA).

Comment: @SimonMourier yes that's kind of my point, in STA how can I tell which one? It's quite easy to call a COM object from the wrong thread - C++ seems to let you and it might even work. So checking would be handy.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such api, but you shouldn't really need this if you control when your objects are created, and on what thread.

Comment: Moreover, in C# if you call STA COM-server from wrong thread, the .net will internally dispatch this call to the correct STA thread and then dispatch the call's result back to the caller thread. So, in C# it's legal to call COM from any thread (but you still need to take care about preventing locks of the STA thread).

Answer (score -1):

You Add reference in the Solution and add a reference to the COM library them you get a new namespace with a set of interfaces and objects. Them You use **new** to instantiate one of those objects.
In this way has no restriction about calling threading model.
Get help here:
[Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809971(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
[Understanding COM Apartments, Part I](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/apts/article.php/c5529/Understanding-COM-Apartments-Part-I.htm)